# iOS: Moving Objects in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have an app that behaves somewhat like a photo gallery. They choose an image from there camera roll, and the image gets displayed in a UIImageView. I have a total of 9 image views. Now, I'm trying to add in the ability to press an edit button, and allow the user to delete photos. I accomplished this by placing a hidden UIButton over each image, and when the button is tapped, a UIAlertView appears asking if they would like to delete that image. After they click "Yes" in the UIAlertView, I would like that particular UIImageView to stop displaying the picture, and move each displayed picture 1 row to the left, so that there isn't a blank space in the gallery.

This is where things get tricky for me, I'm still very new to Objective-C and have no idea how to do this. I know that I should probably call `moveRowAtIndexPath` and `toIndexPath`, but I'm not sure if I should do this in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, or should I just create my own method for this? Here is a sample of what I'm working with, which may or may not be relevant:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    NSLog(@"Image on didenterbackground: %@", imageView);
    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)]];

    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView2.image)]];
     [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView3.image)]];
      [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView4.image)]];

            [self.user setObject:array forKey:@"images"];
    [user synchronize];

            }

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSLog(@"It is %@", self.user);
        NSMutableArray* array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
        imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
        imageView2.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
        imageView3.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:2]];
        imageView4.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:3]];



        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                   object:app];

        backToGalleryButton.hidden = YES;
        tapToDeleteLabel.hidden = YES;
        deleteButton1.hidden = YES;
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }
```

Any help or advice on this is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are those image views in a table view?

Comment: No I'm not, I should have but I'm kind of too far in it too turn back. I will if necessary though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just remove the object from the array if it is a delete function?  removeObject or removeObjectAtIndex will do the job just fine.  If you are using a tableview then call reloadData on it next.

Comment: Cool thank you, I knew I should of used a TableView instead. Is there any simple way to add all of this into a tableview or am I already in too deep? And if I do end up keeping what I have and using `removeObjectAtIndex`, is there a call to reload the data, so that it doesn't leave an empty space in the gallery? Sorry for the novice questions, I'm still very new to this.

Comment: Ah!  I thought this might be the case.  You are worrying that NSMutableArray will behave like a new Java style array I guess.  You think that if you remove it, there will be an empty space in your array.  However, this is not the case.  NSArray cannot contain nil as an object, because it ends with nil, so internally NSMutableArray will shift the back end of your array when you remove an item.  Handy, eh? :D

Comment: Also, nothing is forcing you to use a table view.  We just assumed you were because of what you wrote (IndexPath is an object commonly used in UITableView, and usually never in NSArray)

Comment: Oh awesome, that is great news! Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: Also one more quick question, to accomplish removing an object in the array with the code in the OP, would it look like `[self.array removeObjectAtIndex:@"%@", imagePickerController];` ? I apologize again for the beginner questions.

Comment: No, indexes are integers greater than or equal to zero and refer to the position in the array.  If you want to remove a specific OBJECT from a mutable array, use removeObject instead of removeObjectAtIndex.